# Calculating a point in 3D space

Tags: java, 3d, floating-point, trigonometry, lwjgl

I am trying to locate a point in 3D space relative to the origin (0,0,0).  I have 3 values to calculate this point with: a rotation in degrees about both the x and y axis as well as a "view distance".  Using these values, how can I locate a point in 3D space relative to the origin?  I have tried using basic trigonometric functions, but the results seem to be random. The image below gives a visual as to what needs to be done.

[image]

- 'vd' being the "view distance"
- 'c' being a value holder
- '(x,y,z)' being the coordinate I am trying to find

What I am trying to do is find the point a player is looking at a certain distance away (find a point in the direct line of sight of the player out a certain distance).  Keep in mind, the rotations about the x and y axis are constantly changing, but the view distance remains the same.  If anyone has any suggestions, methods of how to do this, or needs clarification, please comment/answer below.

I am doing this in LWJGL, and the code I am using is as follows:

```
    float c = (float)(Math.cos(Math.toRadians(A00.rot.y)) * view_distance);
    locate.y = (float)(Math.sin(Math.toRadians(rot.y)) * view_distance);
    locate.x = (float)(Math.cos(Math.toRadians(rot.x)) * c);
    locate.z = (float)(Math.sin(Math.toRadians(rot.x)) * c);
```

**EDIT:**

My issue is that this current setup does NOT work for some reason.  The math seems legitimate to me, but I must have something wrong somewhere in the actual setup of the graph..

Comment: Wait, where are you stuck exactly? What has you confused?

Comment: Sorry I wasn't clear there, the way I am currently doing it doesn't work at all for some reason.  It seems to me as though it should, but the coordinates aren't what they are supposed to be.

Comment: Please be specific. How is your current code not working? What results are you seeing when you test it vs what results do you expect?

Comment: I expect a line to be drawn from the origin to a point lining up directly with the viewport which extends for a distance 'vd'.  I am getting a line pointing in a direction which is incorrect.  More specifically, when my rotations are both 0 degrees, the line is pointing somewhere around 90 degrees in the wrong direction (to the left).  When I change the rotation on the y-axis, things just seem to be completely non-coherent.

Comment: Actually, exactly 90 degrees to the left. Strange...

Comment: Funny. I guess the coordinate plane in lwjgl must be different than the plane I am using because making the x coordinate use the sine and the z use cosine, the problem is fixed.  I learned a little lesson in the lwjgl coordinate plane today :D

Comment: I am not familiar with its perspective geometry so am not the one to comment on this. But good for you!

Comment: Thanks for the attempted help!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I suggest looking up quaternions. No need to fully understand *how* they work. You can find ready made classes for java available on the internet as well. Quaternions allow you to represent a rotation in 3D space.

What I would then do, is to start with a vector representing the direction pointing forwards from the origin, and apply the same rotation that the player currently has to it. Now it is pointing in the same direction as the player. Now if you take the player's current point, and the direction vector we now have a ray describing where the player is looking at.

I suggest this link for further information on quaternions. They may look complex but, as I said, you don't need to fully understand how and why they work to be able to use them. Just copy the formulae and learn how they are used. Once you figure out how to use them, they make 3d rotations really easy.

http://content.gpwiki.org/index.php/OpenGL:Tutorials:Using_Quaternions_to_represent_rotation